# How can I make a jQuery function that shrinks a string using a binary search method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jQuery function that will take a string and a fixed width as an input, then through a binary search method (for efficiency) "shrink" that piece of text so it's no longer than the fixed width.

This is what I have so far:

```
function constrain(text, ideal_width){
    var temp = $('.temp_item');
    temp.html(text);
    var item_width = temp.width();
    var ideal = parseInt(ideal_width);

    var text_len_lower = 0;
    var smaller_text = text;
    var text_len_higher = text.length;

    while (true) {
        if (item_width > ideal) {

            // make smaller to the mean of "lower" and this
            text_len_higher = smaller_text.length;
            smaller_text = text.substr(0, ((text_len_higher + text_len_lower)/2));

        } else {

            if (smaller_text.length >= text_len_higher) break;

            // make larger to the mean of "higher" and this
            text_len_lower = smaller_text.length;
            smaller_text = text.substr(0, ((smaller_text.length + text_len_higher)/2));

        }

        temp.html(smaller_text);
        item_width = temp.width();
    }

    var new_text = smaller_text + '&hellip;'
    return new_text;
}
```

Unfortunately this causes a "slow script" that never completes in my browser. Firebug points to line 1131 of jquery.js (version 1.3.2), which is the "unique" jQuery utility, as the culprit. I'm not using "unique" anywhere however.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Dude, Rich B, what the hell is with the odd edits? Editing isn't intended to switch "I've" to "I have" and whatnot.

Comment: @cee: And rolling back is not intended to solve whatever gripes you may have with me. If you see an abusive edit, by all means report it to the mods. Otherwise, mind your own business.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Rich's edit made it a question. That is a good thing. I'd +1 his edit if I could.

Comment: @Marc: Thank you. Hopefully this will put an end to cee's behavior issue.

Comment: Thanks for the edits guys. It does make more sense as a question. :)

Comment: I think you mean binary "search." You're searching for the place where the string exceeds a given width when rendered in the browser.

Comment: @Simon, I think you mean binary search not binary sort

Comment: @Marc: I would hope no one wants that to happen. I will report the other abusive rollbacks as I find them. Thanks.

Comment: @Simon: Sorry for the collision there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you hook up a javascript debugger and check where it crashes?  Use Firebug with Firefox  or MSVS with IE.  If it blows up so hard the debugger dies, step through the function and see how far it gets.

Update based on last comments:  I think you need to step through your code and see how far it gets.  I would be suspicious of a few things:

1. Maybe the width of the object hasn't been recalculated yet (or has become invalid) after setting the new inner text.  It could be that the updated width is not available until later, when the UI does a readjustment.
2. This loop in theory should always terminate, but its possible (especially if the browser is not recalculating the width correctly) the loop could go on forever.
3. You could be splitting an HTML tag when you split the inner text, causing your code to insert malformed HTML perhaps causing the page layout to break.

Comment: Firebug is telling there's an error in jquery.min.js, which I'm sure isn't the culprit here.

Comment: Try debugging with the un-minified jquery. You should be able to get more info about where the error is that way.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I just tried this and it seems to stall on line 1131 of jquery.js (version 1.3.2), which is the return array of the "unique" jQuery utility as far as I can tell. I'm not using "unique" anywhere though. Confused I am.

Comment: Did you check what else is on the callstack?

Comment: @Frank, this is what I have in the callstack:
(?)()
pushStack()
add()
add()
empty()
each()
each()
(?)()
html()
constrain
(?)()
each()
each()
(?)()
(?)()
each()
ready()
(?)()

What's further bizarre (to my unexperienced self, at least), is that after running the script again, Firebug now points to line 26 of jquery.js as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement something that is already there:

the `text-overflow:ellipsis` property of CSS. Unfortunately, it is only supported by IE yet, but a jQuery plugin brings the functionality to Firefox. Google for "text-overflow:ellipsis firefox" as I'm not yet allowed to post links.

Comment: here's a link I found via Franz's suggestion http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/

Comment: Wow - this is great! The CSS solution is (of course) much faster, and it works in Safari 4 too (I did not try with Safari 3). Thanks much!